# How can I expose program data for a sensitivity analysis without breaking modularity?

Tags: oop, fortran, modularity

I have a computer program (Fortran) that contains a great deal of models.  These models contain constant coefficients in the correlations.  Currently, these constant coefficients are all private and local to the routines the models reside in.  However, I'm looking to do a sensitivity study on many of these correlation coefficients, which means I need to be able to change them from their defaults via user input.  I also need this capability to change these parameters to stay current with the code as it is further developed.

The most obvious solution is to slap all of these parameters into their own module, making them all global, and then create a routine to read user input and modify these parameters accordingly.  This absolutely kills the modularity of the code, though.  All of the routines that contain the models that depend on these parameters will be dependent on that one module that holds all the globals.

The other, more labor intensive, solution is to create "setter" routines in each module that has model parameters that will need to be modified.  The parameters stay private in the modules, but they can be modified through the setter routines which can be called from my sensitivity analysis module.

Is there anything else I'm missing?  Any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on how your program is structured, but an approach I like is to use module init/finalize subroutines with default parameters:

```
module paramcalculation
implicit none

real    :: param1
integer :: param2
real,    parameter :: defaultParam1 = 1.0
integer, parameter :: defaultParam2 = 2

contains

    subroutine paramCalcInit( p1, p2 )
        real,    optional, intent(in) :: p1
        integer, optional, intent(in) :: p2

        if (present(p1)) then
            ! do any checking needed
            param1 = p1
        else
            param1 = defaultParam1
        end if

        if (present(p2)) then
            ! do any checking needed
            param2 = p2
        else
            param2 = defaultParam2
        end if
    end subroutine paramCalcInit

    subroutine paramCalcFinalize
        ! clean up any module stuff that needs cleaning up
    end subroutine paramCalcFinalize

    elemental function doParamCalc(x, y)
       real, intent(in) :: x
       real, intent(in) :: y
       real :: doParamCalc
       doParamCalc = param1*x + param2*y
    end function doParamCalc

end module paramcalculation


program testCalc
    use paramcalculation
    implicit none

    real, dimension(5) :: x
    real, dimension(5) :: y
    real, dimension(5) :: z

    x = 10
    y = 2

    call paramCalcInit( p2 = 0 )

    z = doParamCalc(x, y)

    print *, 'Input:  ', x
    print *, 'Output: ', z

    call paramCalcFinalize
end program testCalc
```

Running gives

```
$ gfortran -o params params.f90
$ ./params
 Input:     10.000000       10.000000       10.000000       10.000000       10.000000
 Output:    10.000000       10.000000       10.000000       10.000000       10.000000
```

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking with "setter" routines.  I'm starting to think this is really the correct way to go.